# How can I use a Jenkins pipeline to create a docker image from docker-compose?

Tags: azure, docker, jenkins, docker-compose

I'm trying to build a docker image for elasticsearch and deploy the image (to an Azure registry and have it run as an Azure Web App).

I've done this fine with a `Dockerfile`, but can't work out how to do it with a `docker-compose.yml` file.

Here's my docker-compose:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  elasticsearch:
    container_name: elasticsearch
    image: library/elasticsearch:6.8.15
    environment:
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - ./data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
    networks:
      - backend


networks:
  backend:
    name: backend-network-elasticsearch
```

and my Jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
  environment {
    APP = 'elasticsearch01'
    registry = "utilitaweb.azurecr.io/${APP}"
    registryUrl = "https://___.azurecr.io"
    registryCredential = 'azureregistry'
    dockerImage = ''
    buildNumber = "build_$BUILD_NUMBER"
  }
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Building image') {
      steps{
        ???
      }
    }
    stage('Deploy Image') {
      steps{
        script {
            docker.withRegistry(registryUrl, registryCredential) {
                dockerImage.push()
                dockerImage.push(buildNumber)
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What should I have in the build step?

Previously I've had `dockerImage = docker.build("${registry}:latest", "--build-arg APP=${APP} --build-arg -f Dockerfile .")` or similar, but clearly this won't work.

I think this is down to my lack of understanding of Docker rather than of Jenkins.

Comment: You're already running the Docker Hub `elasticsearch` image; you don't need to build your own.  You may even be able to directly use that image name in your deployment setup.  The build sequence makes more sense if you're building an image from your own source code including a `Dockerfile`.

Answer (score 1):

Docker Compose uses Dockerfiles to build images. In the above `docker-compose.yml` you're not building an image, but rather just using an already built from a registry (as already pointed out by @David Maze).

Most people don't use compose files in production unless they're using Swarm mode. Although it can be used in production, people tend to use Docker Compose in development environments only.

You have two options: a) Bind the build of your Docker image with your application project or; b) Have a separated pipeline just for the building of your Docker images, which is preferred in case you have a lots of images;

In case of A, just have a Dockerfile somewhere in your project's repository and create stages in your pipeline to build, upload and then deploy that image to your container orchestrator infrastructure. It could be a Docker host, a Kubernetes cluster, a Swarm, Fargate, ECS, etc. In the B case, you've already have a base image, which you're gonna import into your project through another Dockerfile. In this secondary Dockerfile, most probably you'll just copy your source code. Then, just upload it to your registry and finally deploy it to your infrastructure.

Best regards.